# Function for inserting values in a nxn matrix by changing directions inside of it

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix

I am relatively new to C++ and I had this task to solve, where you are given a number and you have to create an nxn array of integers, where you would have to continually switch directions (right, down, up, left) until you fill it.

Example:

```
    1     2     3     4
    12    11    10    5
    13    14    9     6
    16    15    8     7
```

I believe I solved it correctly using recursion, but I am not sure if that's the most optimal approach. I know it's not a very difficult task, but if you find it interesting have a look. Any feedback on what I've done is welcome, and possibly how to improve it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int **createDynamicNumArray(int size) {
    int **numArr = new int *[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        numArr[i] = new int[size];
    }
    return numArr;
}


void delArr(int **numArr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        delete[] numArr[i];
    }
    delete[] numArr;
}


void stuffArr(int **&numArr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            numArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}


void printArr(int **arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (arr[i][j] < 10) cout << arr[i][j] << "     ";
            else if (arr[i][j] < 100) cout << arr[i][j] << "    ";
            else if (arr[i][j] < 1000) cout << arr[i][j] << "   ";
            else if (arr[i][j] < 10000) cout << arr[i][j] << "  ";
            else if (arr[i][j] < 100000) cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            else cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


bool inBounds(int rowIndex, int colIndex, int size) {
    if (rowIndex >= size || rowIndex < 0 || colIndex >= size || colIndex < 0) return false;
    return true;
}


bool isFree(int **numArr, int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
    if (numArr[rowIndex][colIndex] == 0) return true;
    return false;
}


void
solveRecursion(bool &right, bool &down, bool &up, bool &left, const int size, int **&arr, int &currNum, int &rowIndex,
               int &colIndex, const int endGoal) {
    if (currNum > endGoal) return; // end-case
    if (right) {
        if (inBounds(rowIndex, colIndex, size) && isFree(arr, rowIndex, colIndex)) {
            arr[rowIndex][colIndex] = currNum; // insert
            currNum++;
            colIndex++;
            solveRecursion(right, down, up, left, size, arr, currNum, rowIndex, colIndex, endGoal);
        } else {
            colIndex--;
            rowIndex = size - colIndex;
            right = false;
            down = true;
        }
    } else if (down) {
        if (inBounds(rowIndex, colIndex, size) && isFree(arr, rowIndex, colIndex)) {
            arr[rowIndex][colIndex] = currNum; // insert
            currNum++;
            rowIndex++;
            solveRecursion(right, down, up, left, size, arr, currNum, rowIndex, colIndex, endGoal);
        } else {
            rowIndex--;
            colIndex--;
            down = false;
            up = true;
        }
    } else if (up) {
        if (inBounds(rowIndex, colIndex, size) && isFree(arr, rowIndex, colIndex)) {
            arr[rowIndex][colIndex] = currNum; // insert
            currNum++;
            rowIndex--;
            solveRecursion(right, down, up, left, size, arr, currNum, rowIndex, colIndex, endGoal);
        } else {
            rowIndex++;
            colIndex--;
            up = false;
            left = true;
        }
    } else if (left) {
        if (inBounds(rowIndex, colIndex, size) && isFree(arr, rowIndex, colIndex)) {
            arr[rowIndex][colIndex] = currNum; // insert
            currNum++;
            colIndex--;
            solveRecursion(right, down, up, left, size, arr, currNum, rowIndex, colIndex, endGoal);
        } else {
            rowIndex++;
            colIndex++;
            left = false;
            right = true;
        }
    }
    solveRecursion(right, down, up, left, size, arr, currNum, rowIndex, colIndex, endGoal);
}


int main() {
    int size, currNum = 1, rowIndex = 0, colIndex = 0;
    bool right = true, down = false, up = false, left = false;
    cout << "Enter N: " << endl;
    cin >> size;
    const int endGoal = size * size;

    int **numArr = createDynamicNumArray(size);

    stuffArr(numArr, size);

    solveRecursion(right, down, up, left, size, numArr, currNum, rowIndex, colIndex, endGoal);

    printArr(numArr, size);

    delArr(numArr, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the rule you're following here?  Using your example, why is there a turn at position 8, when all the other turns only occur when continuing in the same direction isn't an option?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, the rule would be to follow the pattern: left-to-right, up-to-down, down-to-up, right-to-left and repeat (in like an encircling way) as it gets smaller and smaller till the board is full.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bring the whole of `std` into the global namespace.

Prefer to use standard containers (such as `std::vector`) rather than raw-pointers to arrays.  And think about allocation failures - if we create half of our matrix, then we're unable to release that memory if one of the later allocations fails and we catch the `std::bad_alloc`.

Instead of padding using that long `else if` chain, use the `std::setw` manipulator to specify a field width.

Don't use `std::endl` when there's no need to flush output stream.  Ordinary `\n` is much less overhead.

`if (condition) return true; else return false;` is simply `return condition;`, so `inBounds()` and `isFree()` can be simplified.

`SolveRecursion()` could be much simpler.  Instead of passing a set of `bool` parameters, a first simplification would be to use an enumeration value.  But we should consider passing a pair of "step" values (`dx`, `dy`) that can be -1, 0 or 1, and using them to add onto our row and column indices directly.  That would reduce the duplication by a lot.

In `main()` we stream from `std::cin`, but never look to see whether that was successful.  It's an error to use `size` if `>>` failed to assign to it.

No need to `return 0;` at the end - `main()` is a magic function that will automatically return 0 if you run off the end of it.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Using array of pointers because that's what the assignment requires. Took note about including the whole namespace, I will go about it with importing only what I'm gonna use(cin, cout.. etc) or using typedef. Good point about bool functions as well and all the rest! I want to ask though, how would you go about using enum in this situation? I'm not really sure I follow

Comment: My observation is that that function is called with only one of the four booleans set, so we could replace them with a single value from `enum class Direction { North, East, South, West };` and the `if`/`else` chain with a `switch`.  It's only a small improvement, and doesn't do anything to reduce all that duplication of code, but it is a step towards a simpler function.